# Wrong prices at Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have an extension at Chrome Web Store (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twitter-follower-pro/jlfeojddekepkegkdknidjhaggmacfek) that I'm charging for through their official payment system.

Everything was OK but one month ago payments started doing weird things:

1. I got an "upfront" payment although I only accept subscriptions
2. I received payments for a lower amount than stated
3. A customer from Saudi Arabia was charged in Turkish Lira instead of Saudi Riyal

Already got in touch with Chrome Web Store and Google Pay support centers but they didn't solve it. Just told me to contact another team. :(

Did any of you have the same problem? Who should I talk to?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a programming-related problem so it's off-topic on S.O. I think you can try posting on the [official extensions group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/forum/chromium-extensions) as there are several Chromium engineers.

Comment: Sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That is normal. "Upfront" payments are the subsequent payments made by subscribers. "Subscription" is just the first payment. You can see both in the [Developer's Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) under your extension's Stats.
2. You usually receive less than user's pay for, since Google takes their bite ;) If you received less than Google paid, it could be related to your bank fees.
3. Some users decide to access Chrome's Web Store of a different country to find a more advantageous price. For example, if you append `?gl=US` at the end of the URL of the CWS for your extension, you would access the USA webstore and pay in dollars. If you append `?gl=RU`, you would access Russian webstore and pay in RUB (which could be advantageous because of the different prices and currencies). So a user from Saudi Arabia may have wanted to pay the Turkish rate seeing that it was cheaper.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! 1. Why upfront amounts are lower than subscription? 2. No, I mean the charged price is lowerr than it should be. I know the fees and that's not the problem. 3. Oops, they shouldn't allow that!